# Can a Polynesian Ironclad enter ocean tiles?

Tags: civilization-5

Yesterday, when I was playing as Polynesia, I tried to understand if Ironclads will be stronger for Polynesia than for other civs. On the one hand Kamehameha has the wayfinding trait, allowing all units to enter coast and ocean tiles from the get-go. On the other hand, the Ironclad explicitly cannot enter ocean tiles, and unlike the Trireme, no technology can change that. These two facts appear to contrast with each other.

Can a Polynesian Ironclad enter ocean tiles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is that **yes, it can** - A Polynesian Ironclad can enter ocean tiles. This makes this unit pretty decent, especially with the recently-added ability to upgrade it to a Battleship.